# same data types are incompatible when comparing

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
@param text AS
SELECT count(id) from news where col = @param
```

When executing the above stored procedure, an error occurs :

> The data types text and text are incompatible in the equal to operator

Why?

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You should avoid using `text` datatype and could use `varchar(max)` or similar other data type. For your current scenario, you could not use `=` operator with `text` datatype. Instead of that, you can try with `LIKE` as this

```
SELECT count(id) from news where col LIKE @param
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @param VARCHAR(MAX) = 'YourValue';
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM news WHERE CAST(col AS VARCHAR(MAX)) = @param;
```

Comment: it does solve the problem ... but still don't understand why is this error occur ?

Comment: @MoatazAmer You simply *can't* compare `text`, `ntext` and `image` data types.